# Ways to share specific desktop window/region via web?

Tags: screen, remote

Is there a package distributed through Ubuntu which will let me record either a specific window or region/rectangle of my screen, or a website which can do the same? Specifically I would like:

- Free service, or allows a free trial
- Can livecast to web and share using a link (no PINs, registration procedures, etc.)
- Lets me share a *region* of my screen rather than the whole thing.

I've tried a number of Java-based web tools and some Windows ones through Wine, but none seem to allow sharing a specific window:

- Screenleap (option to share window is grayed out)
- join.me (option to share window is grayed out)
- Yuuguu (can't share windows on Ubuntu)
- Screenr (doesn't seem to do live streams).

(P.S. I lack the requisite reputation to create a screen-sharing tag, so I've tagged as best as I could. Please feel free to adjust the tags as needed.)

Comment: I am still interested in an answer. On Windows, I am used to [Region to Share](https://github.com/tom-englert/RegionToShare), but did not find a similar tool for Linux (yet).